# Converting WP theme code to a standalone plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to develop a plugin which creates a snow fall effect on Wordpress websites. My code is below:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: tuhin 
Plugin URI: no plugin uri
Description: This plugin will add a Simple & lightweight responsive slider.
Author: tuhin
Author URI: no author uri
Version: 1.0
*/
/* Launch the plugin. */
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wp_snowfall_plugins_loaded' );

/* Initializes the plugin and it's features. */
function wp_snowfall_plugins_loaded() {
    /* Set constant path to the members plugin directory. */
    define( 'WP_SNOWFALL_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

    /* Set constant path to the members plugin directory. */
    define( 'WP_SNOWFALL_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

    /* Loads the snowfall. */
    add_action('wp_head', 'wp_snowfall_source');
    add_action('wp_head', 'wp_snowfall_effect');
}


function wp_snowfall_source() { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'snowfall', WP_SNOWFALL_URL.'snow.min.jquery.js' );
}

function wp_snowfall_effect() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.fn.snow();
});
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

When I copy this jQuery code in my theme it works, but when I try to convert it to a plugin it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: When you create the plugin do you install and activate it through the admin panel of wordpress?

Comment: Yeahh, I have activated the plugin.

Comment: Have you tried using: `wp_enqueue_script('snowfall', WP_SNOWFALL_URL.'snow.min.jquery.js', array('jquery') );`? Are there any console/php log errors?

Comment: I have used this code just now. And there are not any errors.

Answer (score 0):

try: `add_action( 'init', 'wp_snowfall_plugins_loaded' );` instead

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery wrongly.

- [Don’t Dequeue WordPress’ jQuery](http://eamann.com/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/)
- [Why Loading Your Own jQuery is Irresponsible](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/)

And then, use the following `noConflict` mode to startup your jQuery commands:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    $.fn.snow();
});
```

I tested with [Snowfall version 1.4](http://www.somethinghitme.com/2010/12/09/jquery-snowfall-plugin-1-4/) and this is the working code (note `jquery` enqueued as a dependency for `snowfall`).

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wp_snowfall_plugins_loaded' );

/* Initializes the plugin and it's features. */
function wp_snowfall_plugins_loaded() {
    /* Set constant path to the members plugin directory. */
    define( 'WP_SNOWFALL_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

    /* Set constant path to the members plugin directory. */
    define( 'WP_SNOWFALL_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

    /* Loads the snowfall. */
    add_action('wp_head', 'wp_snowfall_source');

    /* Startup the snowfall. */
    add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_snowfall_effect', 999 );
}


function wp_snowfall_source() { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'snowfall', WP_SNOWFALL_URL.'snowfall.min.jquery.js', array('jquery') );     
}

function wp_snowfall_effect() { 
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
        $(document).snowfall();
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Check out the [Plugin Demo Class](https://gist.github.com/toscho/3804204), it'll upgrade your base plugins. Using constants is not good practice...

Also, research the [`plugin-development`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development) tag at WordPress Answers, lots of useful info ;)